# Docker toolbox (HomeBrew / Tensorflow)

Tags: docker, tensorflow, homebrew, docker-toolbox

*Installing TansorFlow on MacBook. As a part of the installation, I have to install "Docker-Toolbox" for a "Docker"...*

[Comand line screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IQJ6.jpg)

**Why do I get the error** (*check the attached screenshot*) **when I trying to run the command: `brew cask install docker-toolbox`?**

*the error message is*: `Command filed to execute!`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [docker/toolbox issue 153](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/153):

> ### Common problems:
>
> - VirtualBox in an erroneous state. Restarting and/or re-installing VBox may fix this.
> - Check your `~/.bashrc` file. Make sure `DOCKER_HOST` or other docker environment variables are *not* being set.
> - VPN is enabled, meaning docker and docker-machine cannot connect to the VM via it's IP address.
> - Conflict with websense ([link](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/284))
> - Conflict with Avira Antivirus ([link](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=67840&p=347563#p347694))
> - Hyper-V enabled on your Desktop (Windows)

You could try and install VirtualBox separately, before trying your command again.